# android:button tap event on base activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button, android-framelayout

i create a BaseActivity for same layout for all activitys and sliding menu in my app, i have a button in base activity layout and my problem is when i tap on button no things happens and this message shown on log:

```
D/VelocityTracker﹕ Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (Permission denied)
D/VelocityTracker﹕ tpd read x fail: Bad file number
D/VelocityTracker﹕ tpd read y fail: Bad file number
D/VelocityTracker﹕ Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (Permission denied)
D/VelocityTracker﹕ tpd read x fail: Bad file number
D/VelocityTracker﹕ tpd read y fail: Bad file number
I/View﹕ Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{424d3700 VFED..C. ........ 27,27-70,70 #7f070052 app:id/button_menu}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=27.332088, y[0]=3.7002335, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=182860652, downTime=182860652, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
I/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{424d3700 VFED..C. ...p.... 27,27-70,70 #7f070052 app:id/button_menu}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=24.136082, y[0]=3.7002335, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=182860725, downTime=182860652, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
```

this is my base activity layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Put what you want as your normal screen in here, you can also choose for a linear layout or any other layout, whatever you prefer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout"
       >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_menu"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/menu"
            android:text="Ok" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my base activity code :

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

```
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;

protected RelativeLayout mDrawerList;


protected static int position;

private static boolean isLaunch = true;

protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);



    Button btn_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
    btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Log.d("Menu is open","???");
        }
    });


}
```

i don`t understand what is the problem.
can any body help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in your xml..
You are closing an RelativeLayout that doesn't exists..

```
<FrameLayout>
--- <RelativeLayout>
-------- <Button></Button>
--- </RelativeLayout>
--- </RelativeLayout> *THIS*
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: No it's not because of that, this mistake happen on copy past, I edited code.

Comment: Did you see my Log? When I press button this messages shown on logcat.

Comment: @mahdi I saw your LogCat, didn't show up for me. The button toggled the DrawerLayout and your custom Log.d was registered. The idea that I might get from your LogCat is that is there something wrong about the device itself (like being rooted or something). I suggest you try in another device or emulator and see what happens.

Comment: i test it on other device and emulator, i extend main activity from base activity , is views on base activity unaccessable from other activity ?

Comment: when i add button to navigation drawer it`s work but when i add this button to main content it`s not work.

Comment: Hmm .... My device also so give this same error. It was an LG L5 II (E450). And it's rooted. Is there any reason of why rooted devices may give this error?

Answer (score 1):

There is some bug for listview On click in Relative layout, you have to add an attribute called android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to solve..

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
..........
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps..